# Where should I put the Google Nest smoke alarm in this room?

Tags: nest, smoke-detectors

I have a large open plan kitchen dining and living area with a high vaulted ceiling. The ceiling meets two separate one-sided peaks in two places on the wall.

I'd like to put a single Google Nest Protect in the room. Where should it go? The instructions say 90 cm vertical from the peak but doesn't say whether it's ok to place it under a second lower peak.

See photo: [image]

Comment: I would place it in accordance with suggestions on placing smoke detectors in general - it doesn't matter what brand it is. You need it near the peak because that's where the smoke will accumulate first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After consultation with Google customer service, they recommended that the alarm go at the top peak. They did not provide the rationale.

Comment: Thanks for coming back to answer your own question! Be sure to click the check mark so others know this is resolved.